# Custom page for NotFoundObjectResult in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

how can I create a custom page for NotFoundObjectResult results?

Actually when I return this result, the application only displays the id in page.

```
return new NotFoundObjectResult(id);
```

I need to redirect to "/errors/notfound"  every time it gets NotFoundObjectResult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` or `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirect` to the pipeline (before `app.UseMvc`). This will intercept any response with status code between 400 and 600 that **does not have a body yet**.

In your Startup class:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/statuscode/{0}");
```

Then add a new controller:

```
public class HttpStatusController: Controller
{
    [HttpGet("statuscode/{code}")]
    public IActionResult Index(HttpStatusCode code)
    {
        return View(code);
    }
}
```

And add a view Views/HttpStatus/Index.cshtml:

```
@model System.Net.HttpStatusCode
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error " + (int)Model;
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Error @((int)Model)!</h1>
    <p><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></p>
</div>
```

Now you just need to return the desired status code from a controller, without adding any optional body:

```
//These would end up in the new HttpStatus controller, they just specify the status code
return StatusCode(404);
return new StatusCodeResult(404);

//Any of these won't, as they add either the id or an object to the response's body
return StatusCode(404, 123);
return StatusCode(404, new { id = 123 });
return new NotFoundObjectResult(123);
```